# Finding the actual size (area) of an object using intel realsense (d435 camera) depth data

Tags: opencv, 3d, kinect, realsense

I have pair of rgb and rgbd images, which include an object (a tree leaf).    I was wondering how would I figure out the actual area (size) of the object, using the the captured depth values.

For example, if the realsense camera sees the leaf, and the leaf takes 100 pixels of space in the image (in the rgb image), and the depth value the realsense camera gives is x for each pixel of the leaf in the rgb image, how would I know the actual size of the leaf object?

Thanks in advance.